# Qual o melhor modo de criar um contador em Python?

Tags: python

Eu quero criar um contador em Python dentro de uma condicional.

Em C eu faria algo como:

```c
if(condição){
   valor += valor+ objetoDeSoma
}
```

Porém, em Python não consegui achar a melhor maneira de encaixar isso, quando eu faço o código ao tentar printar o valor final do contador (isso fora do `for` que eu utilizo) ele simplesmente não aparece.

Segue o código:

```py
import random
i = int
i = 0
totalProdF = 0
totalProdM = 0
totalF = 0
totalM = 0
for i in range(0,100):
    linhaProd = random.randrange(1,3)
    sx = random.randrange(0,1)
    prod = random.randrange(80,150)

    if(sx==0):
        sexo = "Feminino"
        totalProdF =totalProdF + prod
        totalF = totalF + 1
    if (sx==1):
        sexo = "Masculino"
        totalProdM = totalProdM + prod
        totalM = totalM + 1

    print(i, linhaProd, sexo, prod)

mediaProdMasc = totalProdM/totalM
mediaProdFem = totalProdF/totalF
print("A média de produção masculina foi de: ", mediaProdMasc)
print("A média de produção feminina foi de: ", mediaProdFem)
```

Comment: `randrange(0,1)` retorna um número entre zero e 1, **mas o 1 não é incluso** (ou seja, na prática retorna sempre zero). Portanto, nunca entrará no `if sx == 1`, e o `totalM` será zero e no fim vc estará fazendo uma divisão por zero. Se quer que retorne 0 ou 1, pode trocar para `randrange(0, 2)` ou `randint(0,1)` (ainda sim, vale verificar se o total é zero antes de dividir, pois ainda existe a possibilidade de ser).

Comment: Dito isso, a linha `i = int` não faz sentido, remova. Na verdade, como vc itera pelo `i` no `for`, declará-lo antes é desnecessário. E a variável `linhaProd` não está sendo usada pra nada (só no `print`, mas não entendi o papel dela nos cálculos). Outro detalhe é que se o valor inicial do `range` é zero, ele pode ser omitido (`range(0, 10)` é o mesmo que `range(10)`). Em vez de `valor = valor + 1`, pode ser apenas `valor += 1`. Enfim, daria pra simplificar: https://ideone.com/N4nBtw

Comment: Obrigado, a variável linhaProd é um pedido do usuário, ela deve dar 1 ou 2, vou ver as alterações que você falou, valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, no seu range de sexo ele só pegava o valor 0, uma vez que você colocou (0, 1). Para ele pegar os valores 0 e 1, você deve colocar (0, 2), sempre um valor a mais. Teste o código abaixo:

```
import random
#i = int
i = 0
totalProdF = 0
totalProdM = 0
totalF = 0
totalM = 0

for i in range(0, 100):
    linhaProd = random.randrange(1, 3)
    sx = random.randrange(0, 2)
    prod = random.randrange(80, 150)

    if(sx == 0):
        sexo = "Feminino"
        totalProdF+=prod
        totalF += 1
    elif (sx == 1):
        sexo = "Masculino"
        totalProdM+=prod
        totalM += 1

    #print(i, linhaProd, sexo, prod)

mediaProdMasc = totalProdM/totalM
mediaProdFem = totalProdF/totalF
print("A média de produção masculina foi de: ", mediaProdMasc)
print("A média de produção feminina foi de: ", mediaProdFem)
```

Comment: Foi isso mesmo, muito obrigado!!